# Drupal's "Add to Cart" field shows product variations instead of individual options

Tags: entities, commerce

This is probably a very novice question, but I'm working on a website that uses Drupal Commerce. There is a field defined for the product display called: `Product variations` which is of the format `Add to Cart form`.

On most products, this field correctly shows a combination of size and color dropdowns, whereas for some products, it just puts all products variations in a drop down and shows that instead of the color/size combination.

Any idea what might be going wrong or how to debug this issue?

**Wrong**: 
[image]

**Correct**: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the products you've referenced from the "wrong" image do not all share the same attribute fields in common. One frequent mistake in this regard is forgetting to toggle the checkbox on the field edit form to instruct Drupal Commerce to treat a product field as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms.

Comment: Can you elaborate please where that check box you are referring to is? Also, both these products belong to the same exact content type.

Comment: There are screenshots in the documentation: https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-attributes-variations